# make hover for all elements inside tr

Tags: html, css

I have the flowing table:

```
<tr class="popular-link">
  <td>text</td>
  <td><i class="icon fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg" style="color: green"></i></td>
</tr>
```

And for this the css:

```
.popular-link:hover {color: #c93434}
```

I don't want any text inside i element

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/z5d058z9/1/)

The problem is when I hover over this row, only the text gets the colour, not the `<i>` element. I want when I hover over the row that the text and `<i>` element get this colour.
My question is: Is it possible to have the same rule hover to the `<i>` element?

Comment: The italic element doesn't have any text in it, so what do you expect the text colour to apply to?

Comment: There's something else going on in your styles. [The code as posted works as you want it to.](http://jsfiddle.net/ygyjzzd4/) Please update your question with (as little as possible) extra code to help us repro your scenario.

Comment: color is for text, background-color is for background colors.

Comment: I don't want any text inside i element, the class icon will show an icon (like font-awesome)

Comment: @Jeroen is correct, the current code works: [Example using font-awesome](http://jsfiddle.net/z5d058z9/). You need to edit your question to include a Stack Snippet or [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: yes, you are right, I forgot the inline style, please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this one .It works: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/gnz7o2e9/

```css
.popular-link {
  color: blue;
}
.popular-link *> .icon {
  color: green;
}
.popular-link:hover *> .icon {
  color: grey;
}
.icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="popular-link">

    <td>text</td>

    <td><i class="icon">mock icon</i>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="popular-link2">
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="icon">mock icon</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: with !important works like a charm, I didn't know this rule *> thanks

Comment: !important not working http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/rnfxapn4/ . Only with this global selector works for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Color any for Text, if you want to highlight background use

```
.popular-link:hover
{
background-color: #c93434;
}
```

if you want to change icon color you must design a icon in your color and use that image in hover.

Comment: I dont want the background. I only want the i element to be this colour and without text inside

Comment: than use this css on the i element?

Comment: if i use .popular-link i:hover {color: #c93434} i need to hover exactly where the i is, but I want to hover anywhere on tr and everything will be red

Comment: ok, if you want to change icon, you must design icon in 2 image then use background-position 
.icon 
{
 background-image: url("1.png");
 width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
 background-position: 0 0;
}
.icon:hover
{
 background-position: -32 0;
}

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav